# Removing words between < and > signs in a string c++

Tags: c++

I'm not sure where to go from here. I know something needs to go after `ifstr.get(c)`. It copies the exact words that I have in my text file called `project.txt` but I just need to remove any words that have the chars `<` or `>`?
Any help would be great. Thanks:)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string line;
    char c;

    ifstream ifstr("project.txt");
    ofstream ofstr("past.txt");
    if(ifstr.fail()){
        cout<<"error!"<<endl;
    } // if

    ifstr.get(c);
    while(!ifstr.eof()) {
        cout<<c;
        ifstr.get(c);

        ofstr<<line<<endl;
    } // while

    cout<<endl<<"copy complete"<<endl;

    ifstr.close();
    ofstr.close();

    system ("pause");
    return 0;
} // main
```

Comment: Your title says you want to remove words between "<" and ">". Your problem description says you want to remove words that contain "<" or ">". Can you clarify which one you want?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, that this is what you wanted. Please take a look at the code!

```
//we create a boolean value, to know if we started skipping
bool skipStarted = false;

while(ifstr.get(c))
{
    //if its a '<' and we havent started skipping jet,
    //then we start skipping, and continue to the next char.
    if(c=='<' && !skipStarted)
    {
        skipStarted = true;
        continue;
    }

    //if its a '>' and we started skipping,
    //then we finish skipping, and continue to the next char.
    if(c=='>' && skipStarted)
    {
        skipStared = false;
        ifstr.get(c);
        if(c==' ')
            continue; 
    }

    //if we are skipping, then we go to the next char.
    if(skipStarted)
        continue;

    //otherwise we simply output the character.
    ofstr<<c;

}
```

Comment: Please don't recommend the use of `.eof()` as a loop condition. It almost always results in buggy code. Prefer `while (ifstr.get(c)) { ... }` in this case.

Comment: i never had a problem with eof, but as you wish :)

Comment: Im sorry I am very bad at explaining. example: input= hello world <hello>.     output=hello world.   I need to remove the <hello> with the <>. Thank you so much for helping me.

Comment: my example should do what you want. it should ignore the < and > characters, and anything inbetween them, and write everything else to your outputstream.

Comment: It looks like there was a problem with the spaces inbetween words. Would you know how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Just another shot in the dark:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    ifstream ifstr("project.txt");
    ofstream ofstr("past.txt");
    if(ifstr.fail()){
        cout << "error!" << endl;
    } // if

    bool skipOutput = false;
    do
    {
        string word;
        ifstr >> word;
        if(!word.empty() && word[0] == '<')
        {
            skipOutput = true;
        }
        if(!skipOutput)
        {
            ofstr << word << " ";
            // replicate the output to stdout
            cout << word;
        }
        if(word[word.length()-1] != '>')
        {
            skipOutput = false;
        }
    } while(!ifstr.eof());
    cout << endl << "copy complete" << endl;

    ifstr.close();
    ofstr.close();

    //system ("pause"); Doesn't compile with my system
    return 0;
} // main
```

If you're really just want to filter out words enclosed within '<' and '>' characters this should be sufficient. If you have more complex parsing rules for your `<>` tags you should elaborate your question.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo-code (iostream-esque conditions) for the question in title (also removes the angle brackets):

```
char c;
while (read_char_succeeded(&c))
    if (c == '<')
        while (read_char_succeeded(&c) && c != '>')
            ;
    else
        write_char(c);
```